# How do I disable PrimeFaces column overflow hiding within a datatable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I'm currently working with a `<p:dataTable>` (from PrimeFaces 5.2) with many columns, and as I approach the width of the datatable's parent container, PrimeFaces starts hiding columns; unfortunately it seems to be the most important column (first on the left, a `<p:datePicker>`).

I've tried assigning that column a `priority="1"` and the other columns `priority="3"` as described on [the ShowCase site](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/responsive.xhtml), but the first column is still hidden.

In addition to just nesting the datatable within a `<p:tabView>` I've tried making the dataTable scrollable via `scrollable="true"` and assigning a width, or also try wrapping the datatable within a `<p:scrollPanel>` but the column was still being hidden in either case.

When I remove enough columns (from the right-most of the table), the hidden column will again reappear.

I'm interested in a solution that is not tied/hard-coded to a specific column, as I've run into this same issue on the 2nd column, or 3rd, depending on the resolution or browser width...I want to be sure that my users are seeing everything that was coded into the datatable, even if that means they have to scroll, rather than having a dynamic function suppress values unbeknownst to the user or myself.

Comment: Is it possible to share some code please? As a hint, you could set the width of your datatable automatically by `tableStyle="width:auto"`

Comment: Maybe you can use [column toggler](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columnToggler.xhtml) or [scroll option](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/scroll.xhtml)  ?

Comment: @chaeschuechli - thank you, I'll add some sample code this evening.

Comment: @jNick - the column toggler would give the user the ability to turn off columns that they currently see, unfortunately they're not seeing the required columns. I've tried the scroll option but the column still becomes hidden after several columns are included within the table.

Comment: @chaeschuechli - yes, you nailed it! The `tableStyle="width:auto"` was the missing magic, as soon as I added it to the table, all the columns then displayed as expected.  Could you post this as an answer, and I'll mark it as correct. Thanks again!!

Comment: @Hatley You're welcome. Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, I recommend to add `tableStyle="width:auto"` to a `<p:datatable>` so that you do not have to deal with the single columns width. Primefaces will handle it for you dynamically depending on the length of the column entry.

Comment: OK - I figured out how to accept chaeschuechli's answer, which worked perfectly, thanks a bunch!